# Cache is on, but var/cache is empty?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

I have a magento 1.9.0.1 and all caches are turned on, why is `var/cache` empty? I can only empty the cache from the backend, but when this is broken, I have a problem.

Where does magento write the cache files?

Comment: It could also be a permissions/user/group issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Could also be you are using a different cache storage like `memcached`, `Redis`

Comment: yes, if magent use redis / memcached as cache store then it does not save at var/cache folder

Comment: Where does it save then?

Answer (score 14):

If you have a `var` dir or even a `var/cache` dir, but Magento can't write to it, Magento will use `sys_get_temp_dir()` to determine a good place to put the caching files.

Often this is `/tmp/` and results in `/tmp/magento/var/cache` (Thanks to fschmengler)

Comment: in this case the cache dir is `/tmp/magento/var/cache`

Comment: can you please look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94638/how-does-cache-works-in-magento and reply. I hope you can give enough info

Comment: it   really help me

Comment: Instead of writing thankful comments please upvote, to leave the comment area for "real" comments and questions please :)

Comment: i was already done  this at past .. so no upvote this time  :)

Comment: There is no folder named `magento` in my `/tmp` folder??!

Comment: Then either it is in <magento root>/var as expected and normally or you are using redis, memcached or something else

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this problem when magento writes it cache file to `/tmp/magento/var/cache` folder.

This is weird issue, I had solved this SELinux issue by following command.

```
$ sudo restorecon -R /var/www/html
$ sudo setsebool -P httpd_unified 1
```

Answer (score 3):

To whom it affects. Any file that ends with "`.xml`" can and will be used.
It is not enough to just rename the XML file to something like `oldsomething.xml` you must do something like `local.xml.back` where the file does not end a with dot XML. Leaving `local.xml` and `oldlocal.xml` will load both files.

I don't know enough about the inner workings to know why this is, but I have tested it to know it is true. You can prove this by putting in something that will break Magento in the renamed XML, and Magento stops working.

Maybe the Magento code does not discriminate the file name but just the extension in a certain location?

My website is still on Magento 1.6.2.0
Too shy to update (it ain't broke) but I did put the 1.8 Redis part in  and it seems to work. I am testing 1.9.2.0 but not ready for prime time yet as some of my extensions no longer work.

Try https://github.com/steverobbins/Magento-Redismanager. I like it you may like it too!

Comment: For your information Magento load `.xml` files in `Mage_Core_Model_Config` in function `loadBase()`. It takes all `.xml` with the PHP function `glob()` at the begining `$files = glob($etcDir.DS.'*.xml');`

Answer (score 0):

Manage to solve the issue and it's the weirdest thing ever. When I change the `local.xml` to fix the issue I put a backup of the old file saying `local_back.xml`. I just delete that file and now everything is working fine. No idea why Magento pick that file up. Anyways issue has been solved.

Comment: Because magento is loading every xml file in `app/etc/` as you can see in `\Mage_Core_Model_Config::loadBase`

Comment: i have bigin  magento devloper

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone is not understanding what is happening or my answer, as in the other commits Magento is going to load all that ends with ".xml". So if you want backups or copies that are not used appending back or backup or anything else WILL NOT WORK!

back_local.xml will not work

If you want copies or backups you need to change the suffix of the file name, or in other word in the format of "local.xml.backup or kill the .xml altogether. I use **local.xml.backup** as a copy while I am testing, as I can easily remove the *".backup"* to use it if I want. You can always use 'Save As' in an editor for different versions, like .back_today, or .back2 and such.

> For your information Magento load .xml files in Mage_Core_Model_Config in function loadBase(). It takes all .xml with the PHP function glob() at the begining $files = glob($etcDir.DS.'*.xml'); – Matthéo Geoffray Feb 17 '16 at 14:56

So while testing different backends use the above format.

**As for APC memcached**, they are outdated and do not use keys like **Redis**. From what I understand there is no significant difference between

```
    <session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
```

[files], [db], [memcache] or other cache as it seems to be more of a situation of the server response time and/or hard drives used on the server. See: "[Magento Session Storage: Which to Choose and Why](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/magento-session-storage-which-to-choose-and-why/)?"

When My VPS (InMotion) changed to strictly Solid State Hard drives everything was tremendously faster. I was getting Milli-second transfers!

On my own test servers at home the one box that uses HST 10k spindle speed and a boat load of cache, like 64 MB (Marked for server use), hard drive is very fast and the other box very slow with the Hard drives you get from an OEM box.

Also having 8 CPU cores and 32GB of RAM  helps alot. So much of what is offered on-line as a VPS or even dedicated server is a cheat!!! *You need to get into the details or the resources you will get* as Unlimited means nothing if the server is in reality shared hosting passed off as something else. And don't let the Pictures mislead you as to what their facility might really be. You might get something like Hillary got for her email, just something in a bathroom closet. The hook is they often want a year or more contract to get the good price and it could take a month or more to optimize your setup before you learn you are just on a slow server!!!